# can direct initialization call copy-constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

Like described in [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization)

this syntax means direct initialization

```
`T object { arg };`
```

and if I understand, direct initialization doesn't use copy, it will use assignment, but here in my example I've a direct initialization which pass by copy constructor (this one is used for copy initialization like `T object = otherObject`)

```
#include<iostream>


class A {
    private:
        int m_x;
        int m_y;
    public:
        A(int x,int y):
           m_x{x},
           m_y{y}
        {}

        A(const A& old) {
           m_x = old.m_x;
           m_y = old.m_y;
           std::cout << "copy constructor ! \n";
        }
};


int main() {

    A a{ 10,15 };
    A b{ a };//direct-initialization ! prints copy constructor ! 

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: _"if I understand, direct initialization doesn't use copy, it will use assignment"_ Thats wrong. _"If T is a class type, the constructors of T are examined and the best match is selected by overload resolution. The constructor is then called to initialize the object."_

Comment: Direct initialisation in `T object { arg };` means, essentially, that `object` is constructed using `arg` without creating a temporary and then copying the temporary.   There is no assignment involved.  So if there is a constructor that accepts `arg`  (arguments of its type, or types if `arg` represents more than one value), that constructor is used to construct `object`.   If `arg` is of type `T` then the direct initialisation uses the copy constructor.

Comment: Initialisation never uses assignment. You can only assign to an object that already exists.

Comment: Why shouldn't it invoke copy constructor? Have you read the rules of direct initialization? Quoting... _"If `T` is a class type, ... the constructors of `T` are examined and the best match is selected by overload resolution. The constructor is then called to initialize the object."_ In your case, the **copy constructor is the best match**.

Comment: @Peter As `T` is a class type (in the OPs example), it's actually direct-list-initalization, even if `arg` is a single argument. And indeed a matching constructor overload for `arg` may be chosen ... unless, of course, the argument `arg` somehow finds a valid conversion sequence to a `std::initializer_list` parameter of another constructor overload.